# Location of bash script which executed JAR

Tags: java, bash

I have a bash script that executes my JAR.  I want the JAR (or the java code) to know the location of the script that executed it.  What are some possible solutions for this?

Comment: Does my answer provide the information that you need to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send this information to your java program. In your bash script you get the directory of the bash script:

```
DIR="$(pwd)/$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"
java -jar foo.jar $DIR
```

and in your java code retrieve it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     String path = args[0];
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("error");
  }
}
```

Comment: `pwd` gives the current working directory, which is not necessarily the location of the script.

Comment: You are  right, but the `pwd` mislead me, why do you have it there (not the mention all those quotes)?  i can get the correct directory with just `DIR="$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"`

Comment: Because I wanted to get the full path, **not** relative to where we run script from